# Unity set transform parent without change player's scale

Tags: unity-game-engine, object, position, transform

I'm trying to move my player with a moving floor. It worked when I had set the player's parent transform, as the floor transform. It works well, but with every second, the player's scale changes. Can I set the transform parent without change the player's scale?

Here what I tried:

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("MovingObject"))
        {
            transform.parent = other.gameObject.transform;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the info in the transform is chained info in the hierarchy. This means that changes in the parent, directly change the children.
If you need to maintain the hierarchy and maintain the player's scale, you can multiply by the inverse of the scale applied in the parent, so that the multiplication of scales in the hierarchy is one, and the scale in the children is not affected.

Try:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("MovingObject"))
    {
        transform.parent = other.gameObject.transform;
        PlayerGameObject.transform.scale = new Vector3(
        PlayerGameObject.transform.scale.x/other.gameObject.transform.x, 
        PlayerGameObject.transform.scale.y/other.gameObject.transform.y,
        PlayerGameObject.transform.scale.z/other.gameObject.transform.z)
    }
}
```